# Is it possible to programmatically tell Lotus Notes to generate a new secret key?

Tags: lotus-notes, secret-key

I'm looking for a means to programmatically tell Notes to generate a secret key (like File, Security, User Security, Notes Data, Documents).  Is there such?  It does not appear so.

The goal is to be able to have a template that auto-provisions all of the secret keys necessary for that application to operate.

Comment: You should probably expand on what you want to do, as Secret Keys are normally used as 1:1 communication.

Comment: During application design, secret keys are generated by the designer and given to the Manager, and are then shared by either of those to the end users of the application.  I want to create a template which auto-provisions the ID instantiating that template with a new-instance-specific secret key for that ID owner to later distribute to the people who need access to that app, without having to follow the "create a shared secret key" procedure. An app designer at this point now must edit all uses of secret keys between the template and its instantiations, a sub-optimal pattern for VARs.

Comment: Yup. Sending someone who wants to generate an instance of your app into the security dialogs in the Notes client in order to create a key and manually email it to users who are granted access...  I can't think of a better definition of "sub-optimal pattern" than that. That's the exact reason why I looked into this same issue and talked to friends at IBM about it somewhere around ten years ago. It would be so nice of the app provisioning framework could just do it with a single click.

Comment: It's worse than that. I'm intending to have thousands of instances of these apps, and I need one overseer group to have access to all of them.  Using the same name for different secret keys in all of them is blocked in the library, thus making it impossible to deal with. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Richard mentions there is no direct way to fully automate this, but you can automate some of it.

In Domino 9 it is possible to create secret keys via the Domino console. So you would do something like the following.

```
keymgmt create nek SECRETKEY
keymgmt export nek SECRETKEY FILENAME PASSWORD
keymgmt delete nek SECRETKEY
```

This will create a .key file of FILENAME. You can then mail this file to the end user. However the end user would need to detach the key file and manually import it into notes. They will also need to know the password to import.

[edit]

To expand on this. You could do the following.

1. Create your initial secret keys on the server as per the command above.
2. Create an agent which executes the export with a randomly generated password.
3. Same agent mails the key file, with instructions to install.
4. Same agent sends a second email with the randomly generated password.

It won't stop the end user from forwarding on the key/password to someone not authorised to use the database (which is what an IDK prevents), but you could have some level of auditing this way.

Comment: Creating an IDK file activates functionality in the notes client to import, but I don't have details on creating an IDK at this time except manually. Will look into it.

Comment: @sjcaged checking, IDK can only be created by mailing UI in the security section. The IDK is protected so that only the people you mail it to can import it. Any attempt to forward will corrupt the IDK. So the two pass mentioned above appears to be the only way.

Comment: This is interesting... I created a credstore (apparently an OAUTH credstore) with an NEK I created.  It appears to have a couple of interesting scripts, including a LotusScript for calling LIB_W32:SECCredStoreRemoteRequest(), a LotusScript script library to help register users, and a KeyGen Java library to create AES keys.  It looks like it should work, but why doesn't SECCredStoreRemoteRequest show up in the C API?

Comment: When done in this manner, one single user can only access one single instance of the application, because it's not possible to import multiple secret keys with the same name into the same ID file.

Comment: That's the same for all secret keys. The name has to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the Notes client's secret key generation and management features are not exposed in any of the Notes APIs, including the Notes C API.

Comment: P.S.  I asked IBM for this years ago, for the same reason you are asking.

Comment: I couldn't find it, so I was figuring that it didn't... but I wanted to doublecheck in case I was missing it.  Thanks!