# Is there a way (LotusScript or Formula Language) to obtain a list of document secret encryption keys in the current ID?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus-formula

I'd like to create a SecretEncryptionKeys dialog list field which prepopulates with the names of the available document keys in the current ID.  Is there a way to do so?  I cannot seem to find one in the documentation.  (I can find @Command([UserIDEncryptionKeys]), but that just opens the Encryption dialog.)

This is a follow-on to [Is it possible to programmatically tell Lotus Notes to generate a new secret key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17562397/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-tell-lotus-notes-to-generate-a-new-secret-key) , since I don't want the people who instantiate the new database to have to edit the forms involved to set the default encryption key.  If they do, the next time the design on the database instance is refreshed from the template the settings will be overwritten.

Comment: Does Lotus Notes have an open-source counterpart with roughly similar cryptography features?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I've toyed with the idea of trying to write one, but I seem to totally suck at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last time I checked in with IBM engineers about this, the answer was no.  That was probably about 10 years ago, however I just took a quick look at the [Notes 9 API Reference](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/documentation/capi/) and I don't see anything there that would expose the list of keys, so I suspect that the answer is still no.

Comment: Wow.  For a platform that's supposed to be used by VARs to create secure applications, IBM certainly appears to want to ensure that VARs have incredibly involved workflows, as well as copies of the keys used by their customers.

Comment: They never seemed to get a lot of demand from customers for improving the management of secret keys, which is a shame because it's a very useful feature.

Comment: I have filed enhancement requests.  I doubt they'll take them seriously, but it's a start.

Comment: This sort of feature is going to start getting a lot of attention, soon.